# What to do after signing certificate expire?

Tags: certificate

Let's say I sign application and installer of the app by signing certificate from an certification authority. All customers will download the installer, install the app and use it on various OSes (Windows, Mac, Linux). After two years the certificate expires. I pay the authority for a new certificate for next years and sign the app and installer with the new one.

What happen then?

1. Will the installers and applications be still working for the customers or OSes block them from running?
2. Will the customers need to download a new versions of the installers and install them again?
3. Is it needed to sign older versions of app as well and distribute them to the customers which ended up expired or blocked apps?

Answer (score 0):

On Windows and Linux it's no problem that the signing certificates are expired.
Installs works.

PS: on windows the signing must be timespamped